# How to determine the type of a FormControl when using typed Reactive Forms in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Consider the following simple typed form:

```js
const dateControl = new FormControl<number | null>(null);
const monthControl = new FormControl<MonthOption | null>(null);
const yearControl = new FormControl<number | null>(null);

const form = new FormGroup({
  ['date']: this.dateControl,
  ['month']: this.monthControl,
  ['year']: this.yearControl,
});
```

The type of `this.dateControl` is `FormControl<number | null>`, as you'd expect.

If I wanted to, separately, retrieve the control, so I can work with its value, and therefore I need to be sure of the type of the FormControl and therefore the type of the control value, I might want to use:

```js
const control = form.get('date');
```

The type of `control` is  `AbstractControl<any, any> | null`, again as you might expect as it is grabbing the control via a string.

When working with dynamically generated forms, controls may be added to the form using `addControl` which takes `control: any`.

**Q: Is there any way of determining what the actual type of a `FormControl` is without retaining a reference to a `FormControl` it outside of the `FormGroup`?**

EDIT:

If I construct the form as follows, the type is correct ( `AbstractControl<number | null, number | null> | null`):

```js
const form = new FormGroup({
  date: this.dateControl,
  month: this.monthControl,
  year: this.yearControl,
});
    
const control = form.get('date');
```

Comment: Have you checked FormRecord:https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formrecord?

Comment: I had seen that but can that be used with controls of different types? It didn't seem to be anything sophisticated?

Comment: Once defined within a FormGroup, FormRecord cannot accept different types. If this is needed, then the `UntypedFromGroup` should be used instead. From the docs: `If you need a FormGroup that is both dynamic (open-ended) and heterogenous (the controls are different types), no improved type safety is possible, and you should use UntypedFormGroup.`

Comment: As mentioned in the doc it cant be used with controls with different types.

Comment: So in my example above, the keys are known up front, but the controls are different types. So I think I'd be using `FormGroup` over `FormRecord`, but my question still stands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code, but it seems I can correctly infer the type.

Inside a dummy component class:

```
form = new FormGroup<{
    date: FormControl<string|null>,
    dynamic?: FormControl<string|null>, // dynamic is optional
    name: FormControl<string|null>,
  }>({
    date: new FormControl('2022-01-21'),
    name: new FormControl('Francesco')
  });
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    const val = this.form.get('date');

    this.form.addControl('dynamic', new FormControl(''))
    const dynamic = this.form.get('dynamic');
    
    console.log(val, typeof val?.value);          // Prints FormControl, 'string'
    console.log(dynamic, typeof dynamic?.value);  // Prints FormControl, 'string'
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to use the `addControl` method, then you should define an *optional* FormControl in the FormGroup. However, this might not always be possible if you need to dynamically add many fields. From the docs of the `addControl`:

> In a strongly-typed group, the control must be in the group's type (possibly as an optional key).

---

As a side note, unless you want to explicitly show the type, you can omit to define the primitive type for the FormControls (`new FormControl<string | null>`). Typescript will automatically infer the type `<string | null>` using the Reactive Form API. All types are made `nullable` by default.

If you do **not** want nullable values, you can:

> use the `nonNullable` property of the `FormBuilder` class:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

// Sets all controls to be non-nullable
  const registrationForm = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
    username: '',
    email: ''
  });

  // Sets only the "username" control to be non-nullable
  const registrationForm2 = this.fb.group({
    username: this.fb.nonNullable.control(''),
    email: ''
  });
```

> use the `NonNullableFormBuilder` class (this will make all controls nonNullable)

```
constructor(private nnfb: NonNullableFormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const registrationForm = this.nnfb.group({
    username: '',
    email: ''
});
}
```

Comment: yeah was just adding an edit for that - so its when you add a control using a string as in my original question or  e.g. using `addControl`